# how to dynamically set styles for 'Draw' in OpenLayers + Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, openlayers, openlayers-6

Expected Process:
Select Icon -> Drop Pin ('Feature') -> Pin now has Icon.png on Map

Problem I am facing is setting the style of the pin dynamically (Is that even possible?)

This being the closest I found:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

But I cannot set the 'icon-src' like in here:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-color.html

I understand in the first link that the 'Features' are being dynamically set, but in the second they are hardcoded.

Thoughts?

I have tried to set the styles already inside the VecotorLayer({}) like so:

```
    this.vector = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.source,
      style: {
        'fill-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        'stroke-color': '#ffcc33',
        'stroke-width': 2,
        'circle-radius': 7,
        'circle-fill-color': '#ffcc33',
      }
```

But I cannot use it to set `icon-src`, the 'Feature's get dropped, and I can export them (Get their lat lon to a csv), but I cannot visually see the icons

Comment: If anyone finds this, there is no 'non-janky' way to do this that is not built in. I refactored to Leaflet.js

Comment: You need a StyleFunction which executes when styles get rerendered. You can style there anyway you want based on feature properties.